# How do you migrate Amazon RDS from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

RDS supports MySQL 5.5 and offers a lot of automated feature such as scaling up, expanding disk space, and upgrading the minor version of the database (e.g., from 5.1.49 to 5.1.50).  However, is there a way to upgrade from 5.1.x to 5.5, either through the command line tools or the web GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [RDS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) says:

> Currently, a direct upgrade from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5 is not supported.

so you'll have to do it the more traditional way.

For example a simplistic approach would be to start a 5.5 RDS instance and pipe the 5.1 database into it like this:

```
mysqldump -h mysql5.1.database.host database_name|mysql -h mysql5.5.database.host
```

then switch to using the 5.5 instance.

Of course, this would be slow for a large database and you will need to avoid writes to the source database during the transition.

Comment: Ah, right... it's not currently supported.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6):

Good news, everyone! [Amazon RDS now supports point-and-click upgrade from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/06/20/amazon-rds-mysql-5.1-to-5.5/)

Comment: Two years later...are you serious? I hope it is not going to take them two years to support upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from 5.1 to 5.5 is now available via the AWS Management Console.

I don't know when it was added, but it must've changed recently.

Comment: Actually, it shows it in the menu but it doesn't allow you to do it.  It's meant for people to do minor upgrade from 5.5.8 to 5.5.12